# Sorting gridview on asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hay guys i have a datatable of employees that have 6 column the first one is EmployeID, on page load i bind the data to the gridview and the result is this.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN6LM.png)

as you see on the screenshot the employe id start with
AG0
AG1
AG10
AG11
AG2
AG3
...

and i wanna sort them like.

AG0
AG1
AG2
AG3
AG4
AG5
AG10
AG11
...

Sorry about my english, and thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code of your database query.

Comment: do you mean the stored procedure ??!

Comment: You need to remove AG from employeeid and convert it int and sort

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar questions on SO. Here's one possible option, and you can explore other solutions by yourself (start with: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055971/c-sharp-sorting-a-list-of-strings-that-contains-numbers), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896158/sorting-of-list-contained-strings-having-alphabetic-numeric), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063779/sorting-algorithm-c-sharp)):

```
var list = new List<string>() { "AG1", "AG10", "AG2"};
var ordered = list.Select(s => new { Original = s, Trimmed = s.TrimStart("AG".ToCharArray())})
                  .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Trimmed))
                  .Select(x => x.Original)
                  .ToList();
```